# Opening the login window on clicking on the application icon from dock

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

After closing the application, When i click on the application's icon on dock, i need it to open the login window. I have used,

```
  -(BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)sender hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
  {
  return YES;
  }

 - (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender {
   [[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide:self];
   // [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"MainMenu" owner:self];
   return YES;
  }
```

But when i click on the icon at the dock, the login window is not getting loaded. Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: A Mac application does not have a 'Login window'. It's something special to your app so you need to give us more background what you're trying to do..?

Comment: In my app i have a login window. If i close that login window, the application will not get terminated. If i click on the icon of my application on the dock, again the login window should appear. But it is not appearing for me when i use the above code.

Comment: So you want to app to quit when the window closes?

Answer (score 1):

To close the application when your Login Window is closed (assuming it's the only one opened in your application) you can implement [`applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed%3a)  in your application's delegate:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)app 
{
    return YES;
}
```